# Tenho dois metodos para fazer uma validação como deixar em apenas um?

Tags: java

classe de conexão:

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

    private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/helpsemeq"+"?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASS = "";
    private static Connection conexao;
    public Statement statement;
    public ResultSet resultset;

    public boolean getConnection() {
        boolean result = true;
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
            result = true;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            result = false;
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro na conexão: ", ex);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection con) {
        try {
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection con, PreparedStatement stmt) {
        closeConnection(con);
        try {
            if (stmt != null) {
                stmt.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection con, PreparedStatement stmt, ResultSet rs) {
        closeConnection(con, stmt);
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void executeSQL(String sql) {
        try {
            statement = conexao.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            resultset = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
            System.out.println("Não foi possivel executar o comando: \n" + sqlex + "\n o sql passado foi: \n" + sql);
        }
    }
}
```

aqui o metodo que fica na classe de conexão para executar a query:

```
public void executeSQL(String sql) {
        try {
            statement = conexao.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            resultset = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
            System.out.println("Não foi possivel executar o comando: \n" + sqlex + "\n o sql passado foi: \n" + sql);
        }
    }
```

o outro metodo que fica dentro do jframe:

```
public void validaLogin(){
        try {
            ConnectionFactory conn = new ConnectionFactory();
            conn.getConnection();

            String sql = "SELECT login,senha FROM usuario where login = '" + jTextField1.getText() + "' and  senha = '" + jTextField2.getText() + "'";
            conn.executeSQL(sql);

            //Se houver resultado, ou seja, se validar o usuario e senha, faça algo.
            if (conn.resultset.next()) {
                new NewJFrame1().setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Acesso negado.");
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Erro: "+e);
        }
    }
```

seria possível fazer tudo isso em apenas um metodo?

Comment: Desculpa mas não entendi muito bem sua pergunta. A validação que você diz é a autenticação? E qual o motivo de fazer somente um método?

Comment: Sim isso, tem o método na class de conexão e na class do jframe, eu queria por em apenas um método, pois eu tenho como objetivo também salvar o id na query, após o login ele ira para uma tela onde será possível adicionar ou alterar valores e então queria salvar o id do usuario para alterar no banco de dados de acordo com o id do user. ( ex tem tabela usuario, tem tabela requisições, requisições vai receber o id_login) e então quando mudar ou adicionar uma requisição após ser logado salvar com o id_login do usuario logado.

Comment: Lega, entendi. Acho que tá bem legal seu código. Talvez, uma melhoria que posso sugerir, é criar mais duas classes. Usuario e UsuarioDAO. 
A classe Usuario guardaria o id e a classe UsuarioDAO(Data Access Objetct) forneceria uma instância da classe Usuario com id. Se quiser posso responder mostrando como poderiam ser as classes.

Comment: @rafaelim ficaria muito grato mano, e se você pudesse me indicar algo para estudar mais sobre essas interações com bd, eu estou estudando s.i, mas até o momento só deu java e não teve nenhuma interação com bd :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que tá bem legal seu código. A minha sugestão é criar mais duas classes.
Usuario e UsuarioDAO

Um objeto do tipo Usuario vai servir para guardar o id.

Um objeto do tipo UsuarioDAO vai ser responsável por acessar o banco da dados utilizando a ConnectionFactory que vc criou. Um exemplo seria:

```
class Usuario {
    Long id;
    public Usuario(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class UsuarioDAO {

    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public UsuarioDAO {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;    
    }

    public User autentica(String login, String senha) {
        String query = ...// O código para montar a query
        this.connectionFactory.getConnection();
        this.connectionFactory.executeSql(query);
        ResultSet rs = this.connectionFactory.resultset;
        if (rs.next()) {
            Usuario usuario = new Usuario(rs.getLong("id"));
            return usuario;
        }
        return null; //Se for null, quer dizer que não foi possível autenticar
    }
}
```

E assim, no JFrame vc usa o usuarioDAO.

É legal fazer essa separação para deixar seu código menos acoplado e mais coeso.
Tem alguns princípios de Programação Orientada a Objetos que tratam acoplamento e coesão. DRY, SOLID, Tell Don't Ask são alguns. Vale a pena dar uma olhada!

Sobre indicações de acesso a BD, eu sugiro o google mesmo. Procura por JDBC(Java DataBase Connectivity) que vc vai encontrar muitos assuntos, frameworks e biblioteca para trabalhar.

Boa sorte!

Comment: @rafaellim man você pode me dar mais uma ajudinha manin? estou c um pequeno problema (creio eu)

Comment: Opa, pode falar.

Comment: opa man com relação a esse codigo toda vez q eu faço um login ele vai guardar o id com mesmo que eu mude de tela?

Comment: Pq eu estava pensando em fazer uma tela para dar alguns insert's e precisaria do id desse user logado.

Comment: se tiver como vc da uma olhada nesse topico : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/391457/d%C3%BAvidas-ao-aplicar-um-metodo-dao

Comment: Opa, desculpa a demora pra te responder. Tava em uma semana de treinamento aqui. Se vc estiver usando JFrame, sim. Se nao me engano ele guarda na memória todos os objetos que vc está utilizando.