# Dúvidas ao aplicar um metodo DAO

Tags: java, javafx

Bom tenho 2 classes
a classe Usuario e a classe Requisicao

a minha classe usuario está assim:

```
public class Usuario {
    private static Usuario instance;
    private Long id;
    private String login;
    private String senha;

    public Usuario(Long id, String login, String senha){
    this.id=id;
    this.login=login;
    this.senha=senha;
    }

    public Usuario(String login, String senha){
    this.login=login;
    this.senha=senha;
    }
    public Usuario(Long id){
    this.id = id;
    }
   public static Usuario getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Usuario();
        return instance;
    }
```

Criei um construtor para guardar o ID,
primeira dúvida como eu conseguiria aplicar isso ao meu metodo de validação de login para guardar o ID:
meu metodo de validação:

```
public void validaLogin(){
    UsuarioDAO dao = new UsuarioDAO();
    List<Usuario> usuarios = dao.getList();
    Usuario usuario = Usuario.getInstance();

    for(int x = 0; x< usuarios.size(); x++){
        if(jLogin.getText().equals(usuarios.get(x).getLogin()) && jSenha.getText().equals(usuarios.get(x).getSenha())){
            Principal pr = new Principal ();
            x = usuarios.size();
            fecha();
            try {
                pr.start(new Stage());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else{
            if(x == usuarios.size()-1){
                Alert al = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                al.setHeaderText("Login Invalido");
                al.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

o UsuarioDAO:

```
public List<Usuario> getList(){
   List<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<>();
   String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            Usuario u = new Usuario();
            u.setId(rs.getLong("id_usuario"));
            u.setLogin(rs.getString("login"));
            u.setSenha(rs.getString("senha"));
            usuarios.add(u);
        }
        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
        con.close();  
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        return null;
    }
    return usuarios;
}
```

eu queria que guardasse o id em todas as stages que forem abertas como eu conseguiria isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente a validação do login é feita no banco de dados, não é uma boa prática guardar na sua memória uma lista de usuários com login e senha não criptografada.

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
String sql = "SELECT id_usuario, nome FROM usuario where login = ? and senha = ?";
try {
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

    ps.setString(1, login);
    ps.setString(2, criptografar(senha)); // método qualquer de criptografia

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()){
        Usuario usuarioLogado = new Usuario(rs.getLong("id_usuario"));
        usuarioLogado.setNome(rs.getString("nome")); // vai exibir mesmo o login?
        return usuarioLogado;
    }
    stmt.close();
    rs.close();
    con.close();  
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    return null;
}
return null;
```

Se é para que essa informação fique em todas as telas talvez seja o caso de usar uma variável global na classe principal. (Main.usuarioLogado.getID())

Comment: vlw man, tinha olhado que você estuda na uesc, sou de itabuna .

Comment: tem como você me dizer se está correto essa parte de codigo ?

Comment: public Usuario validarSenha(Usuario u){
    String sql = "SELECT id_usuario, nome FROM usuario where login = ? and senha = ?";
    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        u.setLogin(rs.getString("login"));
        u.setSenha(rs.getString("senha")); 
        if (rs.next()){
            Usuario usuarioLogado = new Usuario(rs.getLong("id_usuario"));
            usuarioLogado.setNome(rs.getString("nome")); // vai exibir mesmo o login?
            return usuarioLogado;
        }

Comment: e tem como você dar um exemplo como eu criaria essa variável global? Seria na classe USUARIO não é?

Comment: A variável "global" seria uma variável declarada como static na mesma classe onde vc tem o método main. Eu não sei se o código está 100% correto, não tenho como testar, mas a sintaxe é essa que eu coloquei. Eu me formei na UESC mesmo, mas não resido mais por ai. Saudações

Comment: eu estou usando javafx e tenho algumas telas, minha dúvida era em qual class declarar essa variavel global, ex tenho tela de login/principal/cadastro/etc